# How can the listener attached to one View (generated by Adapter) call a method of the Fragment it belongs to?

Tags: android, fragment, adapter

We have a ViewPager inside a Layout of an Activity.

We have a FragmentGenerator class which generates Fragment's to the ViewPager Adapter.

Inside the Fragment there are many LinearLayouts, nested or not.

Inside one LinearLayout there is a ListView, which has its own Adapter.

The items of the ListView have their own Layout, which consists of many View's, and one checkbutton named ibOK.

When ibOK is pressed, some other View of the same Fragment must be updated.

Here is current code:

```
public class cAdaptadorListEntries extends BaseAdapter
{
    //...
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
    //...
    // inflate item layout and find ibOK checkbox
    //...
    ibOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
               ibOK.setSelected(false);
               ibOK.setEnabled(false);
               // do something else
               // cGlobalClass.fDoOtherThingsWithGlobalVars();
               GridLayout gltemp = (GridLayout) ((ViewGroup) (ibOK.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent())).findViewById(R.id.glMyGrid);
               gltemp.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
    );
//...
}
```

This code kind of works, and we can acess the GridLayout items successfully. But it is not what we need.

What we really need is to call a member method of the Fragment, which could, in turn, redraw the GridLayout entirely (by changing the text of all its children).

So, finally, the question: how can we call a method of the fragment from the ibOK listener?

Thanks, and sorry for being verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options I can think of.

You can declare the adapter as a non-static inner class in the fragment.  That should allow your adapter to call methods from the containing fragment.

If that's not an option, you can pass a reference to the fragment to the adapter through its constructor, save the fragment reference in the adapter class, and use that reference to call methods on the fragment.

The latter option raises other issues, but if you go that route, that creates a whole different question than this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener in your cAdaptadorListEntries

```
public interface yourListener{
    void ibOKClicked();
}
```

implement your fragment with that listener like

```
public class yourFragment extands Fragment implements yourListener{


@Override
public void ibOKClicked() {
    // Update your fragments Views
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
```

//        .... Write your code and set adapter pass this as listener and other parameters you need.
        yourAdapter = new yourAdapter(this,your Arguments)

```
}
```

I your adapate create a constructor with all perameters and initilize yourListener and from your buttons listener call

```
yourListener.ibOKClicked();
```

to update fragment views.

Comment: Tks, I'll try it. But where exactly do I have to declare the interface?